# Hyperlink not clickable on Internet Explorer but only in Internal Build

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink, scorm2004

I have a SCORM course displayed in an LMS but upon clicking the 'Leave the Module' link it fails to be clickable or do anything. This problem is odd in that it only seems to be exhibited on one browser (Internet Explorer) and only on the internal build. I have this deployed as a cloud service and the link is clickable and works as expected. The HTML code for the link is as follows:

```
<div class="menudiv" onclick="navMenuClick(-1);">
  <div id="TPlainTextBox14D7" style="position:absolute;z-index:5;left:248px;top:423px;width:352px;height:40px;">
    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:#000000">Leave the module</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could it be some sort of MIME type missing on the WebServer for the internal build that is stopping this?

Answer (score 0):

The link was not clickable due to fact that the site was Intranet based and it was rendering the page using a previous version of Internet Explorer as the 'Compatability View' setting is automatically checked for all Intranet sites. I overcame the problem by adding the following code to the relevant page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This forced the page to display in the latest version of IE